# Error in Accessing a Union Member in Constant Expression

Tags: c++, constexpr, unions

I was doing some experiments with unions when I encountered a problem.

```cpp
union U
{
  // struct flag for reverse-initialization of each byte
  struct rinit_t { };
  constexpr static const rinit_t rinit{};

  uint32_t dword;
  uint8_t byte[4];

  constexpr U() noexcept : dword{} { }

  constexpr U(uint32_t x) noexcept : dword{x} { }

  constexpr U(uint32_t x, const rinit_t&) noexcept : dword{}
  {
    U temp{x};
    byte[0] = temp.byte[3];
    byte[1] = temp.byte[2];
    byte[2] = temp.byte[1];
    byte[3] = temp.byte[0];
  }
};
```

This is my sample instance:

```cpp
constexpr U x{0x12345678, U::rinit};
```

I got this error in versions 5.1 and 8.1 of g++ with `-std=c++14`, `-std=c++17` and `-std=c++2a`:

```
accessing 'U::byte' member instead of initialized 'U::dword' member in constant expression
```

Accessing and assigning an element of member `byte`, whether it's from `temp` or `this`, reproduces the error. It seems that `byte` is recognized by the compiler as an "uninitialized" member even though `byte` and `dword` share the same address.

I once modified the second constructor:

```cpp
constexpr U(uint32_t x) noexcept :
  byte{uint8_t(x), uint8_t(x >> 8), uint8_t(x >> 16), uint8_t(x >> 24)}
{ }
```

But I reverted after ending up producing what seems to be a compiler bug:

```
main.cpp:73:37: internal compiler error: in complete_ctor_at_level_p, at expr.c:5844
   constexpr U x{0x12345678, U::rinit};
                                     ^

Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/bugs> for instructions.
```

For my current fix, I added a converter:

```cpp
// converts the value of a uint32_t to big endian format
constexpr static uint32_t uint32_to_be(uint32_t x)
{
  return ( (x >> 24) & 0xFF)       |
         ( (x << 8)  & 0xFF0000)   |
         ( (x >> 8)  & 0xFF00)     |
         ( (x << 24) & 0xFF000000);
}
```

And I modified the third constructor:

```cpp
constexpr U(uint32_t x, const rinit_t&) noexcept : dword{uint32_to_be(x)} { }
```

I'm just curious as to why I'm getting the error. Can anyone help me understand this problem?

### Update:

Based on my recent tests, in a `constexpr` `union` constructor, I can't use a non-static data member that is not in the initialization list. As a result, I added some `struct` flags to explicitly specify the initialization of a certain non-static data member.

```cpp
// struct flag to explicitly specify initialization of U::dword
struct init_dword_t { };
constexpr static const init_dword_t init_dword{};

// struct flag to explicitly specify initialization of U::byte
struct init_byte_t { };
constexpr static const init_byte_t init_byte{};
```

And with it, I also added new constructors for such kind of initialization. Here are some examples:

```cpp
constexpr U(const init_byte_t&) noexcept : byte{} { }

// for some reason, this version does not reproduce the internal compiler error
constexpr U(uint32_t x, const init_byte_t&) noexcept :
  byte{uint8_t(x), uint8_t(x >> 8), uint8_t(x >> 16), uint8_t(x >> 24)}
{ }

constexpr U(uint32_t x, const init_byte_t&, const rinit_t&) noexcept :
  byte{uint8_t(x >> 24), uint8_t(x >> 16), uint8_t(x >> 8), uint8_t(x)}
{ }
```

It would be great if someone can provide a better solution to this.

Comment: g++ 10 and clang 10 seem to accept your alternative second constructor with `-std=c++20`. I'm not sure if this is allowed by the standard, though.

Comment: @lajoh90686: Can you please explain why I should use a copy instead of a const reference?

Answer (score 1):

Your `constexpr` function is invalid before c++20, because it violates the following [rule](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#2.10):

> An expression e is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of e, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> > an assignment expression or invocation of an assignment operator ([class.copy]) that would change the active member of a union;

From c++20, this restriction has been clarified [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.11):

> An expression e is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of e, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> > an invocation of an implicitly-defined copy/move constructor or copy/move assignment operator for a union whose active member (if any) is mutable, **unless the lifetime of the union object began within the evaluation of E;**

Which I believe makes your code valid.

Answer (score 1):

In the last constructor, you create an instance of `U` and assign `x` to `dword`.  `dword` is now the *active* member of that union.
It's undefined behavior to access "byte" if it's not the active member.[0]  UB is not allowed in a constant expression.[1]

Simpler example:

```
union U {
    unsigned int i;
    float f;
};
int main()
{
    const float f1 = U{.i=42}.f; // no error
    constexpr float f2 = U{.i=42}.f; // error
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler output:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:8:35: error: accessing 'U::f' member instead of initialized 'U::i' member in constant expression
    8 |     constexpr float f2 = U{.i=42}.f; // error
      |                                   ^
Compiler returned: 1
```

[0] https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union

[1] https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression